# Unityでプロジェクトを作るたびにPackageManagerの設定が元に戻る

Tags: unity3d, unity2d

タイトルにも書きましたが、現在UnityHubでプロジェクトを作るとPackageManagerの中のVisualStudioEditorのバージョンが2.0.9となっており、2.0.11にアップデートするのですが、UnityHubで新たなプロジェクトを立ち上げると又2.0.9のままに戻ってしまいます。
他にもTestFramework、2DSpriteShape、2DAnimationなどがアップデート待ち状態でアップデートしても新たなプロジェクトを立ち上げると元に戻ってしまいます。
UnityHubとUnityを全部アンインストールして全てインストールし直しましたが改善しません。一体どうすればアップデートしたままになるのでしょうか？

Comment: 新規プロジェクトを作る際に指定するテンプレートが変わらないからでは？ [Hub を使用したプロジェクトの作成](https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/2018.4/Manual/GettingStarted.html), [プロジェクトテンプレート](https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/2018.4/Manual/ProjectTemplates.html), [プロジェクトマニフェスト](https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/2019.4/Manual/upm-manifestPrj.html) 自分独自のテンプレートやパッケージを作ってその最新を更新していけば良いと思われます。[Unityのテンプレートを自分で作る](https://unitytips.hatenablog.jp/entry/2019/05/18/230335), [Project Templateを自分で作る](https://gentome.com/gentomeblog/2840/makeownprojecttemplate/), [パッケージ](https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/2019.4/Manual/PackagesList.html)

Comment: 貴重なアドバイスありがとうございます、リンク先も全て読みました。続きは回答に書きます。

Answer (score 0):

私個人の利用においてはテンプレートをオリジナルでは用意せず直接プロジェクトマニフェストを編集すれば良いかなと思いました。
"/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.13f1/Unity.app/Contents/Resources/PackageManager/Editor/manifest.json"を編集することでプロジェクトを立ち上げた時最新バージョンとすることができました。
中を見る限り恐らくmanifest.jsonの編集だけであればUnityのバージョンが変わってもそのまま利用できそうな気がします。
プロジェクトの作成自体頻繁に行うものではないことは分かっておりますので、たまにマニフェストファイルを編集していきたいと思います。